# Communication between microservices with docker-compose and traefik

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, microservices, traefik

I have a microservice based node app. I am using docker, docker-compose and traefik for service discovery.

I have 2 microservices at this moment:

- the server app: running at node-app.localhost:8000
- the search microservice running at search-microservice.localhost:8002

The issue I can't make a request from one microservice to another.
Here are my docker compose config:

```
# all variables used in this file are defined in the .env file
version: "2.2"
services:
  node-app-0:
    container_name: node-app
    restart: always
    build: ./backend/server
    links:
      - ${DB_HOST}
    depends_on:
      - ${DB_HOST}
    ports:
      - "8000:3000"
    labels:
      - "traefik.port=80"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:node-app.localhost"
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik # The official Traefik docker image
    command: --api --docker # Enables the web UI and tells Traefik to listen to docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"     # The HTTP port
      - "8080:8080" # The Web UI (enabled by --api)
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  search-microservice:
    container_name: ${CONTAINER_NAME_SEARCH}
    restart: always
    build: ./backend/search-service
    links:
      - ${DB_HOST}
    depends_on:
      - ${DB_HOST}
    ports:
      - "8002:3000"
    labels:
      - "traefik.port=80"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:search-microservice.localhost"
volumes:
  node-ts-app-volume:
    external: true
```

Both the node-app and the search-microservice expose the port 3000.

Why can't I call http://search-microservice.localhost:8002 from the node app ? calling it from the browser works though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because node-app is a container and to access other containers it has to use service name and **internal port**.

In your case it is `search-microservice:3000`.

To access host PC and exposed ports, you have to use `host.docker.internal` name for all services and external port.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but since in my docker-compose config I have the mapping 8002:3000 for that service, I should expect the service to be accessible through 8002 right ?

Comment: Not exactly. Exposing means making **accessible outside**. So `8002` will be the port on your **host** PC, but inside docker bridge network exposing has no effect. Containers communicate using original ports

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access other services from in a different container with their hostnames, you can use the "extra_hosts" parameter in your docker-compose.yml file. Also, you have to use the "ipv4_address" parameter under the network parameter for each all services.

For example;

```
services:
   node-app-1:
   container_name: node-app
   networks:
     apps:
       ipv4_address: 10.1.3.1
   extra_hosts:
     "search-microservice.localhost:10.1.3.2"

   node-app-2:
   container_name: search-microservice
   networks:
     apps:
       ipv4_address: 10.1.3.2
   extra_hosts:
     "node-app.localhost:10.1.3.1"
```

[Extra hosts in docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extra_hosts)